# differentiability - neighborhood

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Could someone let me know if I'm on the right track? And if not give me a hint or let me know what doesn't make sense? Thanks in advance!!

> Suppose $f\colon \mathbb{R}\ \to \mathbb{R} $ is differentiable at
>   $x_{0}$ $\in$ $(a,b)$ and $f'(x_{0})>0$. Prove $\exists$ a
>   neighborhood $I$ of $x_{0}$ s.t. $\forall x \in I$ we have $x<x_{0}
>  \implies f(x_{})<f(x_{0})$ and $x>x_{0} \implies f(x_{})>f(x_{0})$.

This is what I was thinking:

Suppose there doesn't exist such an interval $I$. Then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find an $x_{n} \in (x_{0}-\frac{1}{n},x_{0}+\frac{1}{n})$ s.t. if $x_{n}<x_{0} \implies f(x_{n})\ge f(x_{0})$ and if $ x_{n}>x_{0} \implies f(x_{n})\le f(x_{0})$.

 This defines a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, where $x_{n} \ne x_{0} \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $\{x_{n}\} \to x_{0}$.

 Choose $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ to be the subsequence of $\{x_{n}\}$ s.t. $x_{n_{k}} \lt x_{0} \space\forall n_{k}\in \mathbb{N}$. Note $\{x_{n_{k}}\} \to x_{0} $.

 We know $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$. So we have that $\{\frac{f(x_{n_{k}})-f(x_{0})}{x_{n_{k}}-x_{0}}\}$ $\le 0$ so that $f'(x_{0})$ $\le 0$. Contradiction - since by hypothesis $f'(x_{0})$ $\gt 0$. Thus, there does exist such an interval.

Edit: Also, I don't understand where the interval $(a,b)$ comes to play. Why are we given it? We are given the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ so I feel like its redundant information?

Comment: Looks fine, except there may not exist such a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ if only finitely many of $x_n$ are $< x_0$. But in that case you can get a subsequence that is $>x_0$, and arrive at a similar contradiction.

Comment: Ohhh. So if only finitely many of $x_{n}$ are $\lt$ $x_{0}$ then infinitely many have to be $\gt$ $x_{0}$ (and from these you can get a converging subsequence)?

Comment: The original sequence converges, so any subsequence with all elements $>x_0$ will also converge. Then you can adapt your subsequent argument to show $f'(x_0) \le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this is proof by contraposition rather than contradiction.  You wanted to prove “If $A$, then $B$.” You assumed (not $B$), and derived (not $A$), but you didn't use $A$ in your proof at all.  So essentially you proved “If not $B$, then not $A$,” which is the contrapositive of the original statement.  That's more a matter of style than a logical flaw.